# How to tell hibernate to generate a foreign key constraint with 'on update/delete restrict'

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, foreign-keys

Hibernate generates foreign key constraints like this in PostgreSQL:

```
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk4027e58ea8b36313 FOREIGN KEY (fk_responsible_person)
      REFERENCES employee (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

I would like

```
ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

My current annotations:

```
  @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_responsible_person", updatable = true, nullable = true)
  public Employee getResponsiblePerson()
  {
    return m_responsiblePerson;
  }
```

What kind of configuration/annotation do I have to use to get 'restrict' instead of 'no action'?

Comment: Why do you want `RESTRICT` constraints? The only difference between `RESTRICT` and `NO ACTION` is that `RESTRICT` can not be `DEFFERED`.

Comment: I used to work with MS SQL Server, and there `RESTRICT` meant that it was impossible to delete an employee as long as another table had a reference to it. I don't know what `DEFFERED` means.

Comment: Read [`this`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) page. The part which describes foreign keys. In PostgreSQL `NO ACTION` still means it is impossible to delete a key s long as there are references to this key. And ability to `DEFFER` constraint is an ability to postpone the check of this constraint to the end of transaction.

Comment: BTW MS SQL Server does the same with `ON DELETE NO ACTION` - throws the reference integrity error if there are references to the deleted key. And so does ORACLE, and any DBMS that follows ANSI SQL standart.

Comment: Ok thanks for educating me (seriously), I didn't know that `NO ACTION` is basically the same as `RESTRICT`. I've always naively assumed that `NO ACTION` means "no action"... So I guess I'm fine as it is. But back to the original question: How do I control the action with hibernate annotations?